# Can Microsoft TFS support multiple database object versions for production?

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2012 with a SQL Server 2008R2 database.  My company has multiple clients with each using one of three different versions of an application and each version is applying a different version of stored procedure, view, and table (name is hardcoded with version number) database objects in a single database.

I am new to this company and to this multi-version approach all deployed to production.  Does TFS or TFS with Microsoft ALM Ranger support a multi-branch production versioning that does not require multiple physical database copies, each with its own version?  If so, please also provide a link to some good documentation or literature I can review in greater detail.

I am concerned about the complexity of ultimately merging branches in the future.  My preference is to keep a single database and keep the physical object names consistently generic (xxxxx, not xxxx_v1_2 or something like that).  I did check other questions in stackoverflow and other sources, but could not find a clear answer to my question.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with TFS. This seems like more of a question about software architecture.

Comment: Yes, it does pertain to software architecture and how to implement that using TFS.  From my experience, this is a strange setup and I'm not clear as to the best approach to take in achieving this goal.  I do not know if it is logical or even feasible.  Do you have a constructive recommendation?

Comment: What's the  difference between three versions of the application?  Is this application in developing stage or already been  mature product ? It's  difficult to understand why an application has three versions need to have three database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is Team Foundation Server?
>
> Team Foundation Server provides a set
>   of collaborative software development tools that integrate with your
>   existing IDE or editor thus enabling your cross-functional team to
>   work effectively on software projects of all sizes.

Your question is more related to architecture  of database:

- A) applying a different version of stored procedure, view, and table
  (name is hardcoded with version number) database objects in a single
  database.
- B) Holding multiple physical database copies. For single database, keep
  the physical object names consistently generic

Both of the scheme should be support in TFS. TFS just need to be configured with the SQL server which holding the database. Even [configuring TFS with the databases spread across different SQL server instances](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2014/07/07/configuring-tfs-with-the-databases-spread-across-different-sql-server-instances/) is supported. As regards which one is better, it depends on the actual situation of your company.